# Compiling a .NET project using NuGet, PostSharp and Jenkins

Tags: c#, jenkins, nuget, postsharp

I've got some serious problems when trying to compile a C# project in Jenkins which needs NuGet for package management and PostSharp for aspects.
I added `EnableNuGetPackageRestore=true` as an environment variable, and all packages are retrieved every time. PostSharp has been installed in the system, but i still get error every time:

```
error CS1029: #error: 'PostSharp is not introduced in the build process. If NuGet just restored the PostSharp package, you need to rebuild the solution.'
```

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You may have to configure to fetch NuGet packages (especially PostSharp) before you compile/build in Jenkins.

This blog post describes a possible workaround using a batch file: http://blog.overridethis.com/blog/post/2012/02/17/Enable-NuGet-Package-Restore-e28093-When-the-basics-fails!.aspx

Comment: it seems that with nuget package restore there is no need for that, as i get this at the beginning RestorePackages:
  "..\.nuget\nuget.exe" install "dir\packages.config" -source ""  -RequireConsent -solutionDir "..\ "
  Successfully installed 'CommonServiceLocator 1.0'.
  Successfully installed 'Unity 2.1.505.2'.
  Successfully installed 'PostSharp 2.1.7.22'.'